# Setting visibility of a view when a menu item is selected and when we are done with the menu item

Tags: android

I have implemented a menu item to search a list view. I need to make a view invisible when the menu item is selected. This is easily done with this code in my fragment:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            addButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to set the visibility back when I am done with the search (I am using SearchView). I tried to use onOptionsMenuClosed (Menu menu) but that is not being called for some reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `SearchView`?

Comment: Yes, I am using SearchView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setOnActionExpandListener()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false; // change to true if `false` wont work for your case
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

`onMenuItemActionCollapse()` will be called when `SearchView` is collapsed or closed.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I only needed to change return false to return true in the Collapse function. Thank you.